# Understanding extensions in php.ini

Tags: php

I'm having trouble understanding these `;extension=xxx.dll` files in `php.ini`

Is there any document I can refer to which explains these extensions in detail?

Comment: Perhaps this is what you were after: http://php.net/manual/en/extensions.alphabetical.php   (when all else fails look at the manual)

Comment: How do i activate APC extension, SOAP extensions in the php.ini file ?

Comment: To activate an extension, just uncomment the extension line (remove the semicolon). APC, however, is part of PECL, I believe, and is not bundled with PHP by default. Instructions for installing it are here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The .dll files are for PHP extensions. You can read about all of them here: http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.extensions.php

PHP extensions give you extra PHP functionality. They are basically function libraries that add features like MySQL functions, LDAP functions, and even Java functions.

To activate the extensions provided by the default PHP install, simply uncomment the `;extension=xxx.dll` line (remove the semicolon) so that it just looks like `extension=xxx.dll`.

However, not all extensions are bundled with PHP. For example, the PECL extensions, including APC, have to be installed externally. Instructions for installing PECL can be found here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.php

Comment: How do i activate APC extension, SOAP extensions in the php.ini file ?

Comment: please note this doesn't apply to just windows.  PHP wasn't even initially targeting windows in the beginning, and the vast majority of web servers are still on *nix boxes. *nix calls them Shared Dynamic Objects with a .so extension.

Comment: extension=soap.dll ?  on my *nix box i have a soap.so.  It depends on if you have a soap extension compiled for your windows.

Comment: @Jeremy Of course. I decided to link just to the Windows extension page, since he was concerned with .dll files and not .so files. The complete extension list, OS-agnostic, is provided above by Brad F Jacobs.

Comment: Thanx a lot guys, just one more thing though...how do i also activate the memcache extension?

Comment: @Sussagittikasusa Memcache looks like part of PECL...a quick Google should give you more info.

Answer (score 1):

["Extension Writing Part I: Introduction to PHP and Zend"](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1021)

Answer (score 0):

You only need to worry about those if you're running on a Windows server - since they appear to be commented out (`;` at the start of the line) I would assume you're on a Linux server?
In any case, you should be able to look up each extension individually on Google.

Comment: If they are .dll files, I assume he is on a Windows server. If it were a Linux server, they would probably be .so files.